# Analogue of Kodaira surfaces

Tags: complex-geometry, elliptic-curves, elliptic-surfaces

Let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be elliptic curves over $\mathbb{C}$. A (primary) Kodaira surface is a principal bundle $X \to E_1$ with fibre $E_2$. $X$ is a compact complex surface with trivial canonical bundle and so it has Kodaira dimension $0$. In general $X$ is not algebraic (not even Kaehler because $b_1=3$).

The question is: can this construction be generalised to some other fields $k$ (and some appropriate topology)? If the answer is yes what kind of object would one get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow Suwa's construction of the Kodaira surfaces from his paper *Compact quotients of $C^2$ by affine transformation groups*, and define various surfaces which are quotients of $k^2$ by groups of affine transformations of the special form that Suwa arrives at in his paper. I don't know any applications, but it is a very nice paper.

If I remember correctly, every Kodaira surface arises this way, as shown in Inoue, M., Kobayashi, S_ Ochiai, T.: *Holomorphic affine connections on compact complex surfaces* **J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo** 27 (t980)

Comment: For more on the story of Suwa's surfaces, see Bruno Klingler, *Structures affines et projectives sur les surfaces complexes*, Ann. Inst. Fourier
(Grenoble) 48 (1998), no. 2, 441–477. MR MR1625606 (99c:32038)